# How to deal with ember-cli Content Security Policy warnings

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Thats what I do:

```
sudo npm install -g ember-cli
ember new my-app
cd my-app
ember server
```

If I access this server from another computer from LAN with a web browser I get some 'Content Security Policy' warnings and nothing works.

Comment: _Read the error message_.

Comment: This is in [the Ember CLI guide](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#content-security-policy).

Comment: @GJK this documentation only says that I should copy that header not what to do with it ...

Comment: @Larivact, my apologies, it looks like the Ember CLI site has 2 headers with the same ID. Use [this link](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#commonissues) and read the second directly below "Common Issues".

Comment: @SLaks Reading the error message sometimes is not enough

Comment: @emberigniter: But he should at least include the full error in the question.

Comment: Unrelated to this warning, but you will very soon find yourself unable to build your project unless you stop using `sudo` for node related things.

Comment: @runspired but I can't install ember-cli globally without sudo .. what should I do?

Comment: if you can't install it globally without sudo, it likely means you installed either node or nvm with sudo.  The only recourse there is to uninstall node/nvm, uninstall any packages installed via npm with that version of node, and reinstall from scratch without sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the related [docs](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-content-security-policy#ember-cli-content-security-policy).

`ember-cli-content-security-policy` is an addon that apparently comes with Ember out of the box. By default  it only sends `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` which don't actually block anything but you get warnings in the console.

This means you don't have to configure anything to access your ember server from LAN. The reason why nothing worked for me was a stupid mistake in a route.
Because of my lack of understanding of CSP I associated the *nothing works* with these `Content Security Policy` warnings.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you question has been downvoted. These Content Security Policy messages can be annoying.

In Ember CLI you'd need to modify the `environment.js` file to include the policy (inside `ENV`), for example `contentSecurityPolicy: {'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline'" }`

(For a more thorough example you may want to check out what I wrote here: http://emberigniter.com/modify-content-security-policy-on-new-ember-cli-app/ )

Specifically for your case though, assuming your LAN IP is `192.168.1.33`, try with this configuration:

```
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
    'script-src': "'self' 'unsafe-eval' 192.168.1.33:35729",
    'connect-src': "'self' ws://192.168.1.33:35729 http://192.168.1.33:4200/csp-report"
  },
```